# Really freaking great questions to ya' know... promote the site

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

What are some of the best, not necessarily the most popular, but just some amazing questions on Chemistry.SE that I (or we, if ya'll so inclined) can use to promote the site?

Comment: I have a chemistry Facebook page with 3000+ followers that I could use to promote some really good Chem.SE posts.

Comment: [Here's a list of suggestions ;)](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A16683+is%3Aquestion) ${}^{\mathrm{just}^{\mathrm{kidding}^{\mathrm{pleasedontdownvoteme}}}}$

Comment: As usual, thanks for doing this!

Comment: Don't forget to use a link with your referrer id so you can get a badge. See also [A Recipe to Promote your Site](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/), [Announcer, Booster, and Publicist Badges](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/), and [How do I “share” a link for the new badges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63684/how-do-i-share-a-link-for-the-new-badges)

Comment: Melanie, what is the name of your group?

Comment: @electronpusher ChemistryIsTheCoolest